# Initializing DynamoDB Instance has a bad performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm developing Lambda functions with .Net Core 3.1 and trying to use high-level APIs to manipulate the DynamoDB.

```
   var db = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();          // this takes over 2000 ms
   var table = Table.LoadTable(db, "my-table");  // this takes over 1500 ms
```

It looks like a very bad performance but I don't know how to improve it. The Lambda function was deployed in the same region under the same AWS Account.

Comment: How have you calculated the execution time?

Comment: By printing timestamp before and after every steps.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the SDK are you using?

This happens because the DynamoDBClient needs to perform a TLS handshake with AWS when it is first initialized. This will have some effect on performance. As a best practice though, you would do this outside of your function handler. If you initialized your DynamoDbClient and Table in your function constructor this DynamoDB initialization would happen once and then every subsequent invoke in that environment would re-use that same object.

Something like this:

```cs
public class Function
{
    private readonly AmazonDynamoDBClient _client;
    public Function()
    {
        this._client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
    }

    public async Task<APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest apigProxyEvent,
        ILambdaContext context)
    {
        if (!apigProxyEvent.RequestContext.Http.Method.Equals(HttpMethod.Get.Method))
        {
            return new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse
            {
                Body = "Only GET allowed",
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed,
            };
        }

        try
        {
            // Use your _client here

            return new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Body = JsonSerializer.Serialize(product),
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"Content-Type", "application/json"}}
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Error getting product {e.Message} {e.StackTrace}");
    
            return new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse
            {
                Body = "Not Found",
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            };
        }
    }
}
```